# any option in passing lat and log as a input in a weather api

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps

I am using a weather API. and i want to pass latitude and longitude from a geolocation page to the api so that it fetches the current weather . is there any option to achieve this. Please help. your help would be appreciated.
  and here is my JS code:

```
function SearchLocation(e) {

    var searchLocationInput = {
        query: 'Chennai',
        format: 'JSON',
        timezone: 'yes',
        popular: '',
        num_of_results: '',
        callback: 'SearchLocationCallback'
    };

    JSONP_SearchLocation(searchLocationInput);
    e.preventDefault();
}

function SearchLocationCallback(searchLocation) {

    output = "<br/> Area Name: " + locationSearch.search_API.result[0].areaName[0].value;
    output += "<br/> Country: " + locationSearch.search_API.result[0].country[0].value;
    output += "<br/> Latitude: " + locationSearch.search_API.result[0].latitude;
    output += "<br/> Longitude: " + locationSearch.search_API.result[0].longitude;
    output += "<br/> Population: " + locationSearch.search_API.result[0].population;
    output += "<br/> Region: " + locationSearch.search_API.result[0].region[0].value;

    resultContainer.empty();
    resultContainer.html(output);

}
```

and here is my geolocation code:

```
     <html>
   <head>
     <title>Getting Geolocation for Weather Details</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
       <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <style type="text/css">
     html, body {
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
     }
      #map_canvas {
      height: 100%;
     }

     @media print {
       html, body {
        height: auto;
      }

       #map_canvas {
      height: 650px;
      }
     }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
     var map;

      function initialize() {
       var myOptions = {
        zoom: 16,
         mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
       };
       map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),
        myOptions);

       // Try HTML5 geolocation
       if(navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,
                                         position.coords.longitude);

          var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
          map: map,
          position: pos,
          content: '<a href="weatherdetails.html">click here for weather details</a>'
           });

           map.setCenter(pos);
         }, function() {
           handleNoGeolocation(true);
         });
         } else {
        // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
        handleNoGeolocation(false);
        }
    }

     function handleNoGeolocation(errorFlag) {
       if (errorFlag) {
        var content = 'Error: The Geolocation service failed.';
       } else {
         var content = 'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.';
       }

       var options = {
      map: map,
       position: new google.maps.LatLng(60, 105),
      content: content
      };

      var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(options);
     map.setCenter(options.position);
    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
   </script>
   </head>
    <body>
    <div id="map_canvas"></div>
    </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: What "weather API" are you using?

Comment: i am using an Api form worldweatheronline.com

Comment: possible duplicate of [any way to extract lat and long in google maps from a geo location and use in an weather api](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18869834/any-way-to-extract-lat-and-long-in-google-maps-from-a-geo-location-and-use-in-an)

Answer (score 0):

This API is [well documented](http://cdn.worldweatheronline.net/docs/HTMLv4/local_weather_api.htm), pass latitude and longitude, separated by a comma via the `q`-parameter.

Simple implemenation:

```
if(navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      $.getJSON('http://api.worldweatheronline.com/free/v1/weather.ashx?callback=?',
                {format:'json',
                 key:'yourKey',
                 q:[position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude].join(',')
                },
                function(r){
                  alert(r.data.current_condition[0].weatherDesc[0].value);
                })

    });
}
```

Demo: [**http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/xzxZb/**](http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/xzxZb/)